# How to wrap ScrollView contents horizontally?

Tags: react-native

I would like to display the contents of a ScrollView horizontally and have them wrap to a new line when they hit the right edge. For example,

```
|One Two Three Four Five|
|Six Seven Eight Nine   |
|Ten                    |
|                       |
```

where vertical pipes are the edges of the screen.

I've tried messing with the flex styles of the ScrollView and its children, but alas, nothing has worked. I also tried using `horizontal={true}` on the ScrollView, but that doesn't achieve the wrapping effect, and I want it to be vertically-scrollable.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
  <View><Text>One</Text></View>
  <View><Text>Two</Text></View>
  <View><Text>Three</Text></View>
  ...
  <View><Text>Ten</Text></View>
</ScrollView>
```

and this is what that code produces.

```
|One                    |
|Two                    |
|Three                  |
|Four                   |
|Five                   |
|Six                    |
|Seven                  |
|Eight                  |
|Nine                   |
|Ten                    |
|                       |
```

Thoughts on how to achieve my desired effect would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you try with FlatList and his prop numColumns={5} ?

According to this documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#numcolumns

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to use `contentContainerStyle` on the `ScrollView` instead of `style`

```js
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
  ...
```